# Tkinter: What invokes 5 times different values of Configure event when mainloop() starts?

Tags: python, tkinter

I've written a program involves a main function    `do_it()`     and an auto-size function    `resi()`    that are bound with a configure event for receiving real-time changes in size of the root window to resize widgets dynamically , but the size of widgets loaded wrong when    `mainloop()`    starts even though I did't touch anything, then I found the problem is that the Configure event automatically be triggered 5 times with different wrong values, with an inserted print(event) in    `resi()`   , how can I know where the 5 events come from?

```
def resi(event):
    global widroot, heiroot, widcan, heican
    print(event)
    if event.width / event.height >= rat:

        if widroot != event.width:

            heican = event.height
            widcan = round(heican * rat)
            widroot = event.width

        if heiroot != event.height:
            heican = event.height
            widcan = round(heican * rat)
            heiroot = event.height

    if event.width / event.height < rat:

        if widroot != event.width:

            widcan = event.width
            heican = round(widcan / rat)
            widroot = event.width

        if heiroot != event.height:
            widcan = event.width
            heican = round(widcan / rat)
            heiroot = event.height


root.bind("<Configure>", resi)
do_it()
root.mainloop()
```

I got:

```
<Configure event x=398 y=56 width=1 height=1>
<Configure event x=398 y=56 width=567 height=653>
<Configure event x=398 y=25 width=567 height=653>
<Configure event x=0 y=0 width=373 height=653>
<Configure event x=373 y=0 width=194 height=653>
```

Comment: You can add `traceback.print_stack()` into your function, but it probably won't tell you much of interest.

Comment: Do you use geometry() in your root (Tk instance)?

Comment: `print(event.widget)` and you can know which widget involved.

Comment: The code you posted doesn't give the output you say it does. Please create a useful [mcve].

Comment: @acw1668 Oh, this works! I got the widgets, the last one is not from the root window but the another widget. Is there any way to filter them for only events from root window?

Comment: As far as I know, you can filter inside the callback only, i.e. only do what you want when the `event.widget` is root window.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, as @acw1668 suggested, I added a line at the front inside the function for filtering events for those only from root window that appear as `"."`, that works.

```
   def resi(event):
    if event.widget == ".":
        global widroot, heiroot, widcan, heican

        if event.width/event.height >= rat:
...
```